# How to call an HTML file from PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create an administrator login page using HTML and PHP (the PHP is here for several other purposes too) where once the administrator logs in, an HTML file needs to run.

I will include my login page code below. I need to insert the command in the `if` statement in the PHP file. I tried different ways of using the include function; maybe I am not using it right.

Code:

#### PHP file

```
?php

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if ($username =='admin' and $password =='Parthurnax')
    {
        include 'test.html';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'you are not the admin';
    }
?>
```

#### HTML file:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <form action="page.php" method="POST">
                <b>Username:</b><input type="text" name="username"><br>
                <b>Password:</b><input type="password" name="password"><br>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: user `header("location:test.html"); exit():`

Comment: PHP tag inside a PHP tag is totally wrong

Comment: this is only one of many commands I tried , anyways thanks for letting me know that tags should not be nested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
if ($username =='admin' and $password =='Parthurnax')
{
    <?php include 'test.html';?>
}
else
{
    echo 'you are not the admin';
}
```

to

```
if ($username =='admin' and $password =='Parthurnax')
{
    include 'test.html';
}
else
{
    echo 'you are not the admin';
}
```

You have openend PHP tags in an already open PHP script.

Don't forget the test.html page is still accesible without logging in.
If i were to directly put in test.html in my browser, i'd get your protected page.

Change it to a PHP script and check for a logged in user. If the user is not logged in either 301 them to the login page or die your script.

Comment: thank you for letting me know that, but I also used include without the tag it still does not respond

Answer (score 1):

use below if you want to redirect to the new page

```
if(whatever_condition_set_true) {
 header('Location: whatever_page.html');
 exit;
}
```

or
  if your want to include any page based on condition then use

```
if(whatever_condition_set_true) {
   include_once('whatever_page.html');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this code transferred me to test.html, I missed exit in my previous versions, thank you very much

Comment: glad to know it helps. Please accept as answer if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Use `header("yourlink.html");` and don't forget to `exit()`

Comment: Please include more information to your answer, at it stands, it could be a comment.

Comment: This already been posted in the comments `user header("location:test.html"); exit();` Could you please develop your answers a little bit more?See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).